# I need help writing a C++ program that takes two arguments for two functions?

Tags: c++, dictionary, input, analysis

My C++ program needs to take in two arguments text or calc, those are the two functions,

How do I set this up to read in 2 input files using a map?

Comment: You should clarify exactly what your problem is - you need to take arguments, and then you talk about a map - what's the map doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass command line arguments. You can find plenty or resources online. Here are a couple of examples: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/13355/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx.